# Generating a pseudo-natural phrase from a big integer in a reversible way

Tags: sha, bignum, markov-chains

I have a large and "unique" integer (actually a SHA1 hash).

**Note:** While I'm talking here about SHA1 hashes, this is **not** a cryptography / security question! I'm *not* trying to break SHA1. Imagine a random 160-bit integer instead of SHA1 if that will help.

I want (for no other reason than to have fun) to find an algorithm to map that SHA1 hash to a computer-generated (pseudo-)English phrase. The mapping should be bidirectional (i.e., knowing the algorithm, one must be able to calculate the original SHA1 hash from that phrase.)

The phrase need not make sense. I would even settle for a whole paragraph of nonsense. (Though quality — englishness — of a paragraph should probably be better than for a mere phrase.)

A better algorithm would produce shorter, more natural-looking, more unique phrases.

A variation: it is OK if I will be able to work only with a part of hash. Say, first six hex digits is fine.

The possible usage of the generated phrase: the human readable version of Git commit ID, to use as a motto for a given program version, which is built from that commit. (As I said, this is "for fun". I don't claim that this is very practical — or be much more readable than the SHA1 itself.)

*Possible approach: In the past I've attempted to build a probability table (of words), and generate phrases as Markov chains, seeding the generator (picking branches from probability tree), according to the bits I read from the SHA. This was not very successful, the resulting phrases were too long and ugly. I'm not sure if this was a bug, or the general flaw in the algorithm, since I had to abandon it early enough.*

Now I'm thinking about attempting to solve the problem once again. Any advice on how to approach this? *Do you think Markov chain approach can work here? Something else?*

Comment: I don't really know anything about cryptography. So i just want to make sure i understand the question. You basically want to encode a large integer into a unique sentence, so that it sounds as natural as possible ?

Comment: @yurib: yes, that is basically it.

Comment: @yurib: except that I also want to be able to convert this sentence back to that integer later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple approach would be:
 Take list of say 1024 nouns, 1024 verbs and 1024 adjectives each. Your phrase could then be  sentence of the form

```
noun[bits_01-10] verb[bits11-20] adjective[bits21-30] verb[bits31-40],
noun[bits_41-50] verb[bits51-60] adjective[bits61-70] verb[bits71-80],
noun[bits_81-90] verb[bits91-100] adjective[bits101-110] verb[bits111-120] and 
noun[bits_121-130] verb[bits131-140] adjective[bits141-150] verb[bits151-160].
```

With a bit more linguistic thought you can probably construct slightly more complicated ad thus not so repetitive looking sentences (say, a bit for singular / plural, a bit of two for different tenses,...). Longer word lists use up a few more bits but my guess is that you reach rather exotic words quite fast.

Comment: Clever! Well, one more lesson in KISS for me. :-)

Comment: Also: I think that "rather exotic words" could be a half of the fun. (Think "Maverick Meerkat" for example.)

Comment: Does someone know where to get good word corpus, split by nouns verbs and adjectives?

Comment: Looks like that Part of Speech Database here would do: http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

We'll, lets see... The english language [has about 1,000,000 words](http://www.britannica.com/blogs/2009/06/a-million-english-words-give-or-take-half-a-million/). That's about 20 bits per word. SHA1 is 160 bits, so you'll need 8 words. Theoretically, All you'll have to do is to take the n'th word of the oxford english dictionary, where n is a group of 20 bits at a time.

Now, to make it more natural, you can try to add "in/at/on/and/the..." between words, according to their type (nouns,verbs...) using some simple algorithm. (You should remove all these words from your base dictionary, of course).

The algorithm is reversible: Just remove all the words you've added, and convert each word to it's 20-bit index.

Also, try google "insult generator". Some of those generators are pretty nice. I'm not sure about the number of combinations, though.

[You can buy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199563837) the Oxford English Dictionary on CD-ROM with more than 500,000 words (19-bit). I'm not sure if it would be easy to extract the words and their types, however. I'm not sure if it is legal, but I think you can't claim a patent on dictionary entries...

Comment: -1: what is this supposed to mean? it is HASH algorithm, it depends an all data, and you cannot predict collisions, is this super-naive or what?! EDIT: -1 removed, question is ambiguous, conversion of hash into words might be understood un-cryptograhic way

Comment: @peenut: please read my comment to your answer. I'm **not** trying to break SHA.

Comment: @peenut: It's just 160 bits. I'm just suggesting a 1 to 1 mapping between any 160 bit stream and something readable in english.

Comment: @LK: Will it be reversible? (Looks like it would.) OK, nice idea. Any other ideas, how to make the phrase even more natural?

Comment: @LK: Also: do you know where to get a corpus of 1M English words?

Comment: @LK: I think that insult generators use Markovian models.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but [entropoetry](https://indutny.github.io/entropoetry) is a JavaScript (Node/frontend) library that also solves this problem. It combines Markov poetry with Huffman coding, so given the same dictionary (i.e., the same version of the library), converting poetry↔︎numbers will be bidirectional.

Example, from the Node command line:

```
> var Poet = require('entropoetry'); var p = new Poet();
> p.stringify(Buffer.from('deadbeef', 'hex'))
'old trick of loving you\nif you but'
> console.log(p.parse(`old trick of loving you
... if you but`))
<Buffer de ad be ef>
```

And as [technology marches on](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TechnologyMarchesOn), what seemed like a “fun only” idea in 2011 has some real uses in 2017: memorizing cryptocurrency private keys (brain wallet), Dat/IPFS links, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hash function means it is not possible (within reasonable limits) to get a data from hash, unless it is broken (insecure).

Question should be about breaking **SHA-1** hash algorithm - look at Google, it's **not that broken**. So no, you cannot create English phrase from SHA-1 hash code, if you can, please make a huge paper about that, lot of them are useless, this would be breakthrough :-)

**Edit:** if only part of hash is enough, I suggest just brute force (+ simple map of hash<->phrase, possibly in a file or db), breaking hash algorithm is very "strong soup" (difficult problem).

**Edit2:** guys be more specific when asking question, not my fault... I will not delete this so that it scares off any other crypto guys around :-)

Comment: Sorry, I do not ask about extracting information from SHA-1. I ask about *generating* information, using SHA-1 (a big integer) as a seed. This is not a security question.